# CSS. :hover not working on nav>li

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I'm stuck with this for some hours, can't figure out why it doesn't do anything on hover. This is happens only on the li elements.

Here is my code (nav bar) : https://jsfiddle.net/5tobthjx/2/
My css code starts at the very bottom (//My-css).

**As you see I have :**

```
li:hover {
    border: 2px-solid-black;
}
```

Why doesn't it do anything?

I even put a class on the lis : '.li'

**I mean:**

```
   .li:hover {
        border: 2px-solid-black;
    }
```

Comment: Non-parsing syntax is probably not a good source for a question.

Comment: Using a text editor that provides syntax validation?  Chrome tools will also indicate that a CSS rule is invalid due to syntax being incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got the wrong syntax. You have this:

```
li:hover {
    border: 2px-solid-black;
}
```

You want this:

```
li:hover {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

```
li:hover {
    border: 2px-solid-black;
}
```

This is not the way dont use `-` just give a space

```
li:hover {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

Example https://jsfiddle.net/5tobthjx/7/

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the scores:

```
li:hover{
    border:2px solid black;
}
```

this is the right syntax

Answer (score 0):

for specific li in nav ul li

```
nav ul li:hover {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```